# How to get current folder basename in vscode tasks and launch file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I wanna make a C++ program that will all of its code into the an executable file with the current folder name. And this is because I wanna make a project like thing. And the project name is the current folder name and that's why I want the executable to be named with the current folder. But ${fileDirname} variable prints the whole path instead of the basename of the folder. Of course, I can use make file to build them, but the lauch file requires the executable file name, and I can't put the folder name there. And I don't want to change this launch.json for every project. Please help me!!

Comment: See if [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) has a function you can use, like `extension.commandvariable.file.fileDirBasename`

Comment: Unfortunately, I was using gitpod which is a web version of vscode, and it doesn't support this extension :(, I thought gitpod and vscode will act like same but it didn't.

Comment: somebody already made an issue to create a web extension version, I will look into this

Comment: Ok I was also looking for an extension like this. So thanks for this help! :)